# Vue paginated ajax based select

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vue-select

I have a rest end point which returns a list of countries. It takes the following query parameters:

```
searchQuery // optional search string
startFrom // the index in the list from where to return options
count // number of options to return
```

So a query with `searchQuery` as `''`, `startFrom` as `0` and `count` as `10` will return first 10 countries from the list.

A query with `searchQuery` as `Can`, `startFrom` as `5` and `count` as `3` will return fifth to eight country from the list of countries containing the string `Can`.

I want to modify the [pagination](https://vue-select.org/guide/pagination.html) example from [vue-select](https://vue-select.org/) to use above rest api to fetch countries instead of using a static list of countries as is there in the example.

Vue-select docs also has [ajax](https://vue-select.org/guide/ajax.html) based example.

However, because I am new to Vue, I am having some difficulty in combining the two in the way I want.

Can some vue expert please provide some pointers to achieve what I want.

Here is my paginated example with `countries` as a static array of the form:

```
countries: ['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', ...]
```

Template:

```
<v-select :options="paginated" @search="query => search = query" :filterable="false">
    <li slot="list-footer" class="pagination">
      <button @click="offset -= 10" :disabled="!hasPrevPage">Prev</button>
      <button @click="offset += 10" :disabled="!hasNextPage">Next</button>
    </li>
</v-select>
```

Data:

```
data() {
    return {
        countries: // static array as mentioned above
        search: '',
        offset: 0,
        limit: 10,
    }
}
```

Computed:

```
filtered() {
  return this.countries.filter(country => country.includes(this.search))
},
paginated() {
  return this.filtered.slice(this.offset, this.limit + this.offset)
},
hasNextPage() {
  const nextOffset = this.offset + 10
  return Boolean(this.filtered.slice(nextOffset, this.limit + nextOffset).length)
},
hasPrevPage() {
  const prevOffset = this.offset - 10
  return Boolean(this.filtered.slice(prevOffset, this.limit + prevOffset).length)
},
```

How do I convert this to get `countries` from my rest end point?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the work you're doing in fetchOptions function. Basically, you need to pass the pagination data to that function and use this data as query parameters in AJAX request. Provide more code so I could point you a direction to solve it.

Comment: I have updated the question with the pagination example I am trying to modify to ajax.